# Increase a number using ssh

Tags: ssh, sed

Suppose 3 hosts called host1 ,host2, host3
I want to replace the string 5801 on file /etc/FAKEFILE
using +1 for every host,with sed(but perl,awk also ok)
using ssh.
Must return
5802 on host1
5803 on host2
5804 on host3
Thanks

Comment: Are the hostnames somehow included in the file, or do you want to change a string depending on actual machine hostname separately for each machine?

Comment: Depending on machine number,on host1 5802+1 return 5803,on host2 5802+2 return 5804,and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                        

N1=5801
N2=5801

for i in 1 2 3
do
    N2=$((N2 + 1))
    CMD="sed -i 's/${N1}/${N2}/' /tmp/file"
    echo "running $CMD on host$i..."
    ssh user@host$i "$CMD"
done
```